# Busqueda usando LIKE

Tags: mysqli, php7

Estimados estoy realizando un buscador de profesionales los cuales poseen multiples títulos en su currícula, el campo en donde se guardan los títulos los datos estan separados por ,.
Ejemplo 1,5,7,15
El problema que se me presenta es que cuando hago la consulta y busco el titulo 5, me genera el listado pero me incorpora también el titulo 15. Paso el código porque modifico los comodines y deja de andar.
Gracias

```
$query = "
SELECT
*
FROM
matriculas
WHERE especiallidad LIKE '%$titulo%'
ORDER BY ap_matr"
```

Comment: Hola, la parte de tu codigo que dice '%$titulo%' significa = Busca cualquier valor que tenga "$titulo" en cualquier posición.

Comment: Te sugiero leer mas sobre operadores like, pero si tu quieres que tu busqueda en NUMEROS sea exacta y te muestre solo 1 opción ... yo creo que tu problema se resuelve asi 
$query = "
SELECT
*
FROM
matriculas
WHERE especiallidad = '%$titulo%'
ORDER BY ap_matr"

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Dados estos valores: `1,5,7,15` ¿qué resultados debería mostrar? ¿Por qué debe mostrar el `5` y no el `15` en ese caso? No le veo ninguna lógica. Por favor, explícate.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Asumo que tienes lo siguinte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya que mencionas que en el campo "especialidad" se guardan los títulos en una secuencia separa por comas, la consulta

```
SELECT * FROM MATRICULAS WHERE ESPECIALIDAD LIKE '%5%'
```

Claramente devolverá ambos resultados ya que estás indicando que ignore los carateres del lado derecho e izquierdo para encontrar el dato.

Ahora si hago lo siguiente

```
SELECT * FROM MATRICULAS WHERE ESPECIALIDAD LIKE '%5'
```

arrojará el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

porque ignora todos los caracteres a la izquierda hasta encontrar la coincidencia,
y si hago lo siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM MATRICULAS WHERE ESPECIALIDAD LIKE '5%'
```

la consulta no devolverá ningún valor ya que no hay ninguna fila que empiece con valor de 5.

Si lo que tienes es realmente es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces las búsquedas deberías hacerlas con el operador de igualdad (=) para que encuentre la coincidencia exacta.

```
SELECT * FROM MATRICULAS WHERE ESPECIALIDAD = '5'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Una forma poco elegante de hacerlo es considerar las cuatro opciones posibles: que esté al principio de la cadena, que esté en el medio, que esté al final o que sea un valor único.

Tomando el ejemplo de la cadena 1,51,7,15

- `WHERE ESPECIALIDAD = '51'` si solo aparece este valor
- `WHERE ESPECIALIDAD like '51,%'` si está al inicio o entre otros valores
- `WHERE ESPECIALIDAD like '%,51,%'` si está entre otros valores
- `WHERE ESPECIALIDAD like '%,51'` si está al final

Resultando:

```
SELECT * FROM MATRICULAS 
WHERE ESPECIALIDAD = '51' 
OR ESPECIALIDAD like '51,%'
OR ESPECIALIDAD like '%,51,'
OR ESPECIALIDAD like '%,51'
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con FIND_IN_SET

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM matriculas WHERE FIND_IN_SET($titulo, especialidad) ORDER BY ap_matr";
```

Comment: Gracias Jonathan, por ayudarme anda de 10 ;).